# how to handle exception properly if exception occurs while initializing Spring boot web service?

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, webserver, tomcat8

I am getting an exception while initializing spring boot application, because the port is already occupied, here the problem is even after getting exception on startup the java process do not get destroyed, it is still shown in task manager, can some one please suggest on how to properly handle exceptions which occur while initializing spring boot application.

Here is my main function code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException,
        IOException {
    try{
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {   
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Below is the exception which I am getting

```
org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.ConnectorStartFailedException: Connector configured to listen on port 8085 failed to start
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.checkConnectorHasStarted(TomcatWebServer.java:232)
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.checkThatConnectorsHaveStarted(TomcatWebServer.java:224)
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:202)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:300)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
at ocl.vesselModule.webService.App.main(App.java:91)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
```

Screenshot of the task manager process
[image]